# Block UIAnimation not being called when If() is in play

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The animation here is never called despite the method getting a full run.

Other Method

```
 if (show) {
    [self dropTheHeader];
}
```

and

```
   -(void)dropTheHeader{


    NSLog(@"Show this damn method");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.searchHeader.frame = CGRectOffset(self.searchHeader.frame, 0, -44);
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         self.searchHeader.hidden = YES;

                     }];
}
```

its so odd. the Log gets called and everything, just no animation. Checked to see if self.searchHeader is Nil, no dice. Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT

```
2013-09-26 11:34:47.362 Pict[3077:907] searchHeader hidden: no
2013-09-26 11:34:47.364 Pict[3077:907] the current frame is: {{0, 0}, {320, 88}}
2013-09-26 11:34:47.366 Pict[3077:907] the new frame is: {{0, -44}, {320, 88}}
2013-09-26 11:34:49.411 Pict[3077:907] the completed frame is: {{0, 0}, {320, 88}}
```

Comment: can you confirm the frame of searchHeader change? try assigning some fixed cgrect to see if the animation happens

Comment: Also, in completion block, check the finished boolean before hiding the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know what the output is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     NSLog(@"searchHeader hidden: %@", self.searchHeader.hidden ? "yes" : "no");
                     NSLog(@"the current frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.searchHeader.frame));
                     self.searchHeader.frame = CGRectOffset(self.searchHeader.frame, 0, -44);
                     NSLog(@"the new frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.searchHeader.frame));
                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     if (finished) {
                         NSLog(@"the completed frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.searchHeader.frame));
                         self.searchHeader.hidden = YES;
                     } else {
                         NSLog(@"completion handler called before finishing animation");
                     }

                 }];
```

Comment: alright man, added it to the question so you can see it easier

Comment: its so weird, it seems to be something with the if() statement for sure, because if I remove it, it runs just fine. But I cannot find anyother people with similar problems

Comment: Do you have auto-layout turned on in IB? Or any constraints set in IB? Are you moving it around somewhere else that could override the animation which runs asynchronously? It can't be just the if statement.